# MXE record on AWS Route53

Tags: dns, web-hosting, amazon-route53, mx-record, namecheap

Namecheap offers a handy external mail service in their Advanced DNS called MXE. You just put in the IP address of the account you have created elsewhere in cPanel and you can collect external email. Works great.

I am switching over to Route53 and hope to do the same, but there is no MXE option available in the list? How can I replicate this in Route53?

- CName points to Cloudfront in Route53 which in turn points to S3 website hosted bucket
- Mail hosted at 154.32.45.2, running on a cPanel

I tried adding an MX record with "10  155.94.234.2" but it doesn't seem to produce the same results as MXE on Namecheap

How can I replicate this in Route53?

Answer (score 0):

So the correct answer was to add an mx record ( 0:mail.mydomain.com ) and create an A record for mail.mydomain.com that pointed to the ip address for the domain on cpanel.